# Ecommerce product catalog Wordpress classic-list.php plugin add price

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a catalog with wordpress. I want to show the price :

[image]

The used plugin is [code](https://github.com/impleCode/ecommerce-product-catalog/blob/master/templates/themes/classic-list.php) :

```
 if ( $archive_template == 'default' ) {
        $product_id              = $post->ID;
        $archive_price           = apply_filters( 'archive_price_filter', '', $post );
```

I tried to solve this but I got errors. I'm new in PHP.

So how to get this work?

```
$return .= '<div class="product-short-descr"><p>' . c_list_desc( $post->ID ) . '<p></p></p></div></div>'; Ander this line need be a price php code.
```

Comment: What is the errors you got?